# MVC Edit Page with DropDownLists

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm relatively new to the MVC Framework so I'm pretty sure this is an easy question to answer. I would like to make an edit page for a user profile with a lot of drop down lists. I'm thinking the best way is to create a viewmodel called **ProfileViewModel** which has an object to represent the **Profile** I want to edit i.e. the concrete values of the entity and then a bunch of properties of type IList to contain the possible values for each property on the profile.

For example let's say there is a user that has a profile with Gender equal to male and ethnicity is Caucasian. The possible choices for gender is male, female (I know there more, I'm not trying to get political) and ethnicity is Caucasian, African American, Latin, etc. I would like to pass the user but also the lists of possible choices.

1) I have 15 lists. Is it best practice to send all of them in one view model or should I separate into partial views for each drop down?

2) How would I create the choices in the dropdownlist and then select the choice matching the profile object? Should I pass the entire viewmodel back when saving the entity even with the possible choices included?

3) Should I have a different view for the create and edit pages. The only difference would be in the edit page I would need to select values in the dropdownlist corresponding to the profile object.

Bonus question:

4) Do I always have to create a viewModel (dto) or can I just pass the entity framework object directly to the view. I'm using code first poco class.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 4) Do I always have to create a viewModel (dto) or can I just pass the
>   entity framework object directly to the view. I'm using code first
>   poco class.

It is not a good idea to mix your ORM side entities to be used in your UI layer. The best practice is to create a separate view model **SPECIFIC TO THE VIEW**.

> 3) Should I have a different view for the create and edit pages. The
>   only difference would be in the edit page I would need to select
>   values in the dropdownlist corresponding to the profile object.

It is up-to you. But you may consider creating a partial views which is included in your create and edit view. One partial view can have all text inputs and second one can have the dropdowns(If you can group all dropdowns together in the view).

> 2) How would I create the choices in the dropdownlist and then select
>   the choice matching the profile object? Should I pass the entire
>   viewmodel back when saving the entity even with the possible choices
>   included?

You will have another property in your view model to hold the selected value. When using this property and the proper overload of DropDownListFor, you will be able to select an option in the dropdown

```
public class EditProfileVm
{
  public List<SelectListItem> Genders { set;get;}
  public string SelectedGender {set;get;}
}
```

And in your Action method

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
  var vm = new EditProfieVm();
  vm.Genders = new List<SelectListItem> { 
         new SelectListItem { Value="M", Text="Male"},
         new SelectListItem { Value="F", Text="FeMale"}
        };
  vm.SelectedGender="F";  //Set the selected option here
  return View(vm);
}
```

And in your view

```
@model EditProfileVm
@Html.DropDownListFor(s=>s.SelectedGender,Model.Genders)
```

> 1) I have 15 lists. Is it best practice to send all of them in one
>   view model or should I separate into partial views for each drop down?

Totally depends on your use case/requirement, There is nothing wrong in sending 15 dropdowns in the view model. But seeing 15 drop downs in the UI will make the user a little unhappy as it will be so convoluted. You may consider some sort of wizard approach where you will hide and show some part of your profile info as user clicks in Next button.